# C Character Array Pointer is not a valid statement

Tags: c, arrays, unix, pointers, char

we were given an assignment that would take in two commands from the terminal and pipe the first one into the second. I believe I have the structure of the code correct, however, when trying to compile it complains that my initial char *cmd is not a valid statement. Why is this happening? I'm confused, any assistance would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f_des[2];

    if(pipe(f_des) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1: perror("fork");
            exit(2);
            case 0: dup2(f_des[1], fileno(stdout));
            close(f_des[0]);
            close(f_des[1]);
            char *cmd[] = {"/usr/bin/"+argv[1],argv[1], (char *)0};
            char *path[] = {"HOME=/usr/home/", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0};
            int ret;
            ret = execvp(cmd,path);
            exit(3);
        case default: dup2(f_des[0], fileno(stdin));
            close(f_des[0]);
            close(f_des[1]);
            char *cmd[] = {"/usr/bin/"+argv[2], argv[2], (char *)0};
            char *path[] = {"HOME=/usr/home/", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0};
            int ret;
            ret = execvp(cmd,path);
            exit(4);
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 22: Invalid statement.
char *cmd[] = {"/usr/bin/"+argv[1],argv[1], (char *)0};
^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 22: Missing ";".
char *cmd[] = {"/usr/bin/"+argv[1],argv[1], (char *)0};
-----------------------------------------------------^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 23: Invalid statement.
char *path[] = {"HOME=/usr/home/", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0};
^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 23: Missing ";".
char *path[] = {"HOME=/usr/home/", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0};
------------------------------------------------------------^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 24: Invalid statement.
int ret;
^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 27: Invalid expression.
case default: dup2(f_des[0], fileno(stdin));
-----^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 30: Invalid statement.
char *cmd[] = {"/usr/bin/"+argv[2], argv[2], (char *)0};
^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 30: Missing ";".
char *cmd[] = {"/usr/bin/"+argv[2], argv[2], (char *)0};
------------------------------------------------------^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 31: Invalid statement.
char *path[] = {"HOME=/usr/home/", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0};
^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 31: Missing ";".
char *path[] = {"HOME=/usr/home/", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0};
------------------------------------------------------------^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 32: Invalid statement.
int ret;
^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 25: In this statement, "ret" is not declared.
ret = execvp(cmd,path);
^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 25: In this statement, "cmd" is not declared.
ret = execvp(cmd,path);
-------------^
cc: Error: lab1.c, line 25: In this statement, "path" is not declared.
ret = execvp(cmd,path);
-----------------^
```

Comment: You can't add two strings with `+` like `"/usr/bin/"+argv[1]`. Don't make up syntax just because you can do that in other languages.

Comment: And it looks like you're compiling as C89. And it's `default:`, not `case default:`.

Comment: @YuHao, Thanks for the notice, how would you suggest doing it? strcat?

Comment: @shellter, I've read error many times but as you can see I do in fact have a semicolon so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @shellter, I did attempt your solutions of adding the additional semicolon within the curly brackets but it still results in the same error messages.

Comment: In due course, when you've fixed all the other problems, you can realize that `execvp()` doesn't require you to prefix the command name with `/usr/bin` (it will search on `$PATH` anyway; that's what the `p` indicates), and the only return value from `execvp()` is `-1` because it only ever returns if it fails, so there's really no point in capturing the result in `ret`, especially as you don't subsequently use `ret`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks for the explanation. After I attempted to remove the /usr/bin as suggested I am still stuck with the same set of errors. One for each char *. One indicates that is an invalid statement and one indicates that I am missing a semicolon. I have no doubt that they are connected in some way but I am confused as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: Which compiler are you using, on which platform?  You're using a feature that is only available in C99 or C11, not in the old C89/C90, but it looks like your compiler is assuming C90.  If you can't set compiler options to work in C99, you'll have to move the variable declarations to just after an `{`, if necessary adding the `{` and matching `}` to create a block in which you can declare the variables.  For example: `case 0: { char *cmd[] = { argv[1], argv[1], (char *)0 }; ... break; }` or thereabouts.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have no idea what compiler is be used as I am just a student connecting to a unix server last updated in the 90s so probably something old. I will try your solution though.

Comment: If it was last updated in the 90s, then (a) you should find a better place to study — the equipment shouldn't be more than a decade old — and (b) you can safely assume it is not supporting C11 and empirical evidence indicates it is not supporting C99 by default. Which variant of Unix is it running?  Try `cc -V` or `cc -v` or `cc -version` or `cc --version`; one of those might produce a version number. `uname -a` contains lots of information too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, this is what I got,  $RCSfile: crt0.s,v $ $Revision: 1.1.21.11 $ (DEC) $Date: 1995/09/06 19:54:27

Comment: So, you're running a DEC compiler, perhaps on an Alpha, perhaps on a VAX?  Anyway, a date in 1995 precludes C99 or C11 support.  So, you'll have to make sure that your variable declarations only appear at the start of a block, before any executable statements, as in my suggested workaround.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I appreciate all of your help, it seems that my compiling problems are now solved. Now on to try and understand the rest of the failure. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I try to remove the errors. I am not sure this is working correctly.

```
char *cmd[] = {"/usr/bin/"+argv[1],argv[1], (char *)0};
```

change the + as ,.

```
char *cmd[] = {"/usr/bin/",argv[1],argv[1], (char *)0};

case dafault:
```

to

```
default:
```

And make the cases as with in a block. using the parameters. `{ }`.

While passing the argument to the execvp first argument is `char *` not  `char *[].`

Then try this code. I am not sure this is working, but the all errors is cleared.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f_des[2];

   if(pipe(f_des) == -1)
    {
       perror("pipe");
       exit(1);
     }

     switch(fork())
     {
         case -1: perror("fork");
                 exit(2);
         case 0: { dup2(f_des[1], fileno(stdout));
                   close(f_des[0]);
                   close(f_des[1]);
                   char *cmd = "/usr/bin/";
                   char *const path[] = {"HOME=/usr/home/", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0};
                   int ret;
                   ret = execvp(cmd,path);
                   exit(3); }
         default: { dup2(f_des[0], fileno(stdin));
                   close(f_des[0]);
                   close(f_des[1]);
                   char *cmd = "/usr/bin/";
                   char *path[] = {"HOME=/usr/home/", "LOGNAME=home", (char *)0};
                   int ret;
                   ret = execvp(cmd,path);
                   exit(4); }
        } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to concatenate to strings in C/C++, you use `<string.h>`'s `strcat(const char *,const char *)` function. Secondly, the second argument for `execvp()` is `const char *argv[]`. Third, the first argument is for `execvp()` is `const char *cmd` not `char *cmd[]`, but `char *cmd`. It has to be a single string. Also, it is `default:` not `case default:`, as you put in your code. Fourthly, you should declare `ret`,`cmd`, and `path`/`cmdargs` outside of the switching statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int f_des[2];

 if(pipe(f_des) == -1)
 {
     perror("pipe");
     exit(1);
 }

 char *cmd;
 char *cmdargs[/*<numcmdargs>*/];
 int ret;

 switch(fork())
 {
    case -1: perror("fork");
        exit(2);
    case 0: dup2(f_des[1], fileno(stdout));
        close(f_des[0]);
        close(f_des[1]);
        cmd = strcat("/usr/bin",argv[1]);
        cmd = strcat(cmd,'\0');
        ret = execvp(cmd,cmdargs);
        exit(3);
    default: dup2(f_des[0], fileno(stdin));
        close(f_des[0]);
        close(f_des[1]);
        cmd = strcat("/usr/bin/",argv[2]);
        cmd = strcat(cmd,'\0');
        ret = execvp(cmd,cmdargs);
        exit(4);
 }
}
```

Note: this code will compile with no warnings on clang, but will probably require some modification to run. (It gives a `Bus Error: 10` when run).